# STL regex_match failing to match ^.*

Tags: c++, regex, stl

I'm an experienced C++ developer, but relatively new to STL. I haven't used STL in any previous projects. I'm trying to use regular expressions to parse the Windows services file (`Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services`) and my expression works fine in Notepad++ (after I remove the doubled backslashes added for C string literals), but my STL code is failing to match the same expression and text. I've debugged into it, and the best I can tell, I think it's matching the "e" to [A-Za-z], and then failing to match "c" to [^ ]* possibly because it's not seeing the range as negated. I get past the `_N_if` node in the STL regex code, and then the `_N_rep` node fails as (nested a few levels deeper in the call stack) it's processing a `_N_class` node. The `_Node=>_Flags` value is `_Fl_final` (4), which does not contain the `_Fl_negate` (1) flag.

Here, I think, is the essential code I'm trying to debug:

```
std::basic_regex<TCHAR> re(_T("^([A-Za-z][^ ]*)\\s+(\\d{1,5})\\/(tcp|udp)\\b.*"), std::regex_constants::ECMAScript);
//...
std::match_results<const TCHAR*> mr;
if (std::regex_match(szLine, mr, re))
```

I believe the content of szLine is

```
echo                7/tcp
```

It looks like the "e" gets matched, and then the "c" fails if my debugging skills are good.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

**Edit:** szLine ends with a newline. I wonder if that could be causing the match to fail because `.` doesn't match newline by default?

Comment: What compiler/version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013, just added to the question with an edit.

Comment: I ran the sample you've provided and without the new line it works but after I add the new line to the `szLine` it doesn't. I added `\\n?` to the regex and now it works in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to remember when using `regex_match` that the match must apply to the whole string, including the newline if one exists. Remembering that `.` does not match a newline by default, the answer here is to add `\\n?` to the end of the C string literal, which resolves to `\n?` going into the pattern, which matches an optional newline at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

In order to match any symbol including a newline, you can use a `[\s\S]` (or `[\d\D]` or even `[\w\W]`) character class.

Also, your regex wouldn't match the string you provided, as there is no second `\d+`. Here is a sample code that will work with `regex_match`:

```
string line = "echo                7/tcp\n"; // <-- \n is added
string regexStr = "^([A-Za-z][^ ]*)\\s+(\\d{1,5})/(tcp|udp)\\b[\\s\\S]*";
//                                                            ^^^^^^^^^    
regex rg(regexStr); 
smatch sm;
if (regex_match(line, sm, rg)) {
        std::cout << sm[1] << std::endl;
        std::cout << sm[2] << std::endl;
        std::cout << sm[3] << std::endl;
    }
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/h8upfl)

Results are:

```
echo
7
tcp
```

Comment: Actually the regex and string I provided do match with no other alteration besides the addition of \n. There is only 1 digit in the example string.

Comment: Sorry, my daughter must have typed something on the keyboard while I was feeding her :)